# How to pass from a sequence to a chain?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> Let $C$ be a compact convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (in the standard topology) and let us define the partial order on $\mathbb R^n$ as if $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k),y=(y_1,...,y_k)$ then $x\leq y$ if and only if for all $i$, $x_i\leq y_i$.
>
> Suppose $A$ is a chain in $C$ (under this order). Let $z_i=\inf\{t_i:t=(t_1,...,t_k)\in A\}$ and take $z=(z_1,...,z_k)$. Show that $z\in C$.

I need some help on this. I could show this when $A$ is finite.

When $A$ is infinite, I want to use the argument that passing onto subsequences, if necessary, I can have coordinatewise convergence. I don't know if this can be used, but I think this would be a method. Also I don't think convexity is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations are correct. You can construct a sequence in $A\subset C$ that is converging to $z$ in the following way. Take $b^i \in A$ with $b_i^i \leq z_i+1/m$ and you get a set $\{b^1,\ldots,b^n\}\subset A$. Now take the minimum of this set with respect to your ordering and call this element $x_m$. In this way you get a sequence $(x_m)_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ and this sequence converges to $z$ since

$$\Vert x_m-z\Vert\leq \sqrt{n\cdot(1/m)^2}=\sqrt{n}\cdot\dfrac{1}{m}$$

which goes to zero as $m$ goes to infinity. Since $C$ is compact you have that $z \in C$.

Note that you don't actually need that $C$ is compact you only need it to be closed nor to you need convexity.

Comment: I have worked out the solution, thanks anyway!